# Varchar(max) issue in SQL Server Native Client 11.0

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I trying to import a data to sql server via SSIS, and one of the column is varchar(max) data type. And I received below error. It seem like SQL Server Native Client 11.0 does not support varchar(max). Anyone can comment and how can I resolve this. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSIS read Columns with data type of `Varchar(Max)` as `DT_TEXT` data type (BLOB Column) So you have to do some workaround:

1- If you can change your source column data type to `Varchar(8000)` (*8000 is the maximum length for varchar data type*)

2- Add a script component and mark your column as an input and add an output column of data type `DT_STR(4000)` and in your script use the following function to convert your `DT_Text` column content to a string

```
string BlobColumnToString(BlobColumn blobColumn)
{
    if (blobColumn.IsNull)
        return string.Empty;

    var blobLength = Convert.ToInt32(blobColumn.Length);
    var blobData = blobColumn.GetBlobData(0, blobLength);
    var stringData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(blobData);

    return stringData;
}
```

*Note: Varchar can store up to 8000 characters (nvarchar = 4000), while varchar(max) can store 2 GB.*

Comment: Does it mean this is limitation in SQL SERVER NATIVE CLIENT 11.0 ?

Comment: No i think that is also in newer version of sql server.

Comment: This issue is because Varchar can store up to 8000 characters (nvarchar = 4000), while varchar(max) can store 2 GB